# Syntax error with XML load special charracters

Tags: php, xml, syntax-error

I have simple code but data assign does not work on fields with `-` in variable. Here is sample:

```
$row = $xml -> Kundendaten[$i];
          {
          $code = $row -> article-number;
          $ean  = $row -> EAN-code;
          $manuf = $row -> manufacturer;
          $price = $row -> price_EUR_1;
          $stock = $row -> stock; }
```

it works fine for variables `stock`,`manufacturer` and `price` but not for `article-number` and `EAN-code`.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables with hyphens need to be accessed like this:

```
$row->{'article-number'}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot!